# Calculation of the projection on a closed convex set in a complex Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Given $H=\ell^2(N,C)$ a complex Hilbert space, $N$ and $C$ representing the set of Natural and Complex numbers respectively, and $A=\{x=(x_n)\in H;\ \forall n\in N,\ x_n\geq 0\}$ a closed convex set.

The question is, *determine the projection on the convex set A*.
Here is the response they gave which I do not fully understand:

*It is necessary and sufficient this time to note that $y=P_A(x)$ verifies for all $z$ in $A$ that:*
$$\Re e(<x-y,z-y>)=\Re e\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}(x_n-y_n)\overline{(z_n-y_n)}\right)\leq 0.$$

*In all cases $z_n-y_n$ is real, and hence*
$$\Re e(<x-y,z-y>)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(z_n-y_n)\left(\Re e(x_n)-y_n\right).$$

*We are then led to suppose $y_n=\Re e(x_n)$ if $\Re e(x_n)\geq 0$ and $y_n=0$ otherwise.*
*We conclude  that the previous quantity is negative.*

Now the part I do not understand is when it is said: **in all cases $z_n-y_n$ is real**. How can this be since both *$z_n$* and *$y_n$* are sequences of complex numbers?

Comment: Because $z,y$ are sequences in $A$, which I assume is the set of sequences of **real** positive numbers (since the condition $x_n\geqslant 0$ in the definition of $A$ makes no sense if $x_n$ is not a real number, as complex numbers have no order)

Comment: I get it in that sense. So *z and y* are just real sequences in a complex Hilbert space in this case? Also what would be the need of writing $\Re e(x_n)$ instead of $x_n$?

Comment: Because $x$ is a general element of $H$ (of which we want to find the projection $P_A(x)=y\in A$), so it's a sequence of complex numbers. Also yes, both $z,y$ are elements of $A$, so they must be sequences of real numbers

Comment: It's clear now!